# ImageView image not showing on Eclipse + Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I have all my pictures saved in the drawable-xhdpi folder. I have a total of six images, it shows 4 but not the last two despite me using the same code for both in the xml file.

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
            android:onClick="food"
            android:src="@drawable/foods" />
```

^ That one is viewable

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
            android:onClick="parking"
            android:src="@drawable/parking" />
```

^ This one isn't.

This is what I get when viewing through Graphical Layout

The following classes could not be found:
 
- ImageView (Change to android.widget.ImageView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Again, both images are contained within the same folder. It might be obvious, I'm relatively new to android.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: Not sure what that is but I'll give it a look, thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to copy the source file into the directory, maybe something went wrong during this process so try copying the actual image file to where it must be in your project. That should fix it

Comment: Still didn't fix it : / 
Thank you for your help though Kabuto

Comment: Did you try going to `Project` -> `Clean...` from the top bar in eclipse? Maybe a good old restart of the graphical view might help as well.

Comment: I think I figured it out thanks to you. I went to clean it and then came across an "already defined" error. Turns out I had a txt file with the same name under drawable-hdpi. Thank you!

Comment: Yep that was it. Post your comment as an answer so that I may accept it and give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Project` -> `Clean...` from the top bar in eclipse. Then a good old restart of the graphical view might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

i faced same problem , if you are using image saved .icon extension it may cause this problem.
change your image type. hope this help.

Comment: This should be a comment